# How to access a GET variable in Ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

Assume that my server got a GET Request as

> www.example.com/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1320729329&hub.verify_token=Hello

I want to echo the part hub.challenge back. How can I do that in Ballerina language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@http:QueryParams` for this. Refer following example :

```
import ballerina.net.http;
import ballerina.lang.system;

@http:BasePath {value:"/shop"}
service echo {

    @http:GET{}
    @http:Path {value:"/order"}
    resource echoGet (message m, @http:QueryParam {value:"orderid"}string orderid) {
        system:println("orderid" + orderid);
        reply m;

    }
}
```

A GET request as http://localhost:9090/shop/order?orderid=123 would get set to variable `orderid`, which you can then use in further implementation. (Please note I used `system:println` for the purpose of the example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this error after that. `ballerina.lang.errors:Error, message: value
        at echo.echoGet(handler.bal:12)`

Comment: This is because when making the get request the message m is not available. I have modified the sample to fix this error. (removed http:convertToResponse(m); statement)

Comment: Thanks. Can we printout the `orderid` in a html page by using ballerina?

just like in php (echo orderid; )

Comment: No Harshana.. since this is an integration language, I do not think such support is within the scope for future as well.. What you can do easily is to set the orderid to the message and reply with that. This way, you can see the response (with orderid) using a REST client.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621416/outputtng-html-by-using-ballerina for an answer