# Outputtng html by using Ballerina

Tags: html, wso2, ballerina

Is there any way to output a html page with some data in it by using Ballerina language?

Assume that I need the "orderid" string in the below code to be displayed inside a H1 tag in a HTML page..

```
import ballerina.net.http;
import ballerina.lang.system;

@http:BasePath {value:"/shop"}
service echo {

    @http:GET{}
    @http:Path {value:"/order"}
    resource echoGet (message m, @http:QueryParam {value:"orderid"}string orderid) {
        http:convertToResponse(m);
        system:println("orderid" + orderid);
        reply m;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballerina is an Integration Language and hence does not support such functionality. However, as an alternative, you can try something as below.

```
import ballerina.net.http;
import ballerina.lang.messages;
import ballerina.lang.xmls;

@http:BasePath {value:"/shop"}
service echo {

    @http:GET{}
    @http:Path {value:"/order"}
    resource echoGet (message m,@http:QueryParam {value:"orderid"}string orderid) {
        xml xmlPayload = xmls:parse("<html><h1>" + orderid + "</h1></html>");
        messages:setXmlPayload(m, xmlPayload);
        reply m;
    }
}
```

This constructs an HTML and outputs a reply as below:

```
<html>
    <h1>123</h1>
</html>
```

This is still not HTML, rather an HTML constructed as an XML. If you need to render in a webpage, you can extract XML payload directly to be used in your rendering.

**Please note that the XML support in Ballerina is under redesign at the moment to provide better native like support. Hence, the above example implementation may change in future.**